# Javascript local datetime into selected timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, daterangepicker

I have https://www.daterangepicker.com/ which outputs some datetimes.

If I am in timezone (device timezone)   Europe/Kiev (GMT+3) the outputs will be in those timeszones. For example 27 June 2022 12:00:00 am GMT+3. (midnight)
[image]

```
var output = 1656277200000;
```

I also have the user that selects a timezone for example user selects London (GMT+1).

```
var timezone = "Europe/London";
```

I want to convert that  output unix time from 27 June 2022 12:00:00 am GMT+3 to the timezone of what the user selected, the London timezone: 27 June 2022 12:00:00 am GMT+1. That means the unix: 1656284400000

[image]

Comment: there is already library day.js or moment.js which may help you.

Comment: warning: it's hard. better to use a library.

Comment: well, which library and how ? I already have moment.js but not sure how to do it

Comment: MomentJs recently announced that the library is now deprecated. The creators recommentd looking into Luxon, Day. js, date-fns, js-Joda, or even replacing Moment with native JS.

Comment: 27 June 2022 12:00:00 am GMT+3 and 27 June 2022 12:00:00 am GMT+1 **are not the same instant in time**. The first occurs 2 hours before the second, it converts to 26 June 2022 10 pm GMT +1. I suggest you learn about timezones and offsets and how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this way**

```
// Without moment-timezone
new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "America/New_York" });

// With moment-timezone
var moment = require("moment-timezone");
const today = new Date();
var timeGet = moment(today);
timeGet.tz("Asia/Karachi").format("ha z");
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to convert the timezone to an integer representing GMT. Then you subtract your timezone from theirs. You can convert the difference to milliseconds and add it to the original unix time.
Example if your timezone is +5 and theirs is +7:

```
const myTimezone = 5;
const theirTimezone = 7;
const diffarance = theirTimezone - myTimezone; // set to + 2
const differenceMilliseconds = diffarance * 3600000;
const theirUnix = myUnix + differenceMilliseconds;
```

This also works if the the difference is negative.

Comment: There is no difference between "theirUnix" or "myUnix" for the same instant it time, they are exactly the same for everyone everywhere, regardless of timezone. "UNIX timestamps" are offsets from the UNIX epoch. ECMAScript uses the same epoch, so conversion between the two is pretty simple.